# Slow/heavy query, can it be made more efficient?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the query below - which works, but it takes about 80 seconds to run in MSSMS. I am wondering if it can be made more efficient?

An explanation will follow below.

```
SELECT A.courseid, A.studentid, attendanceStatus, lessonDate,
 (SELECT top 1 SnoozeFrom FROM [tblConsecutiveSnooze] C 
     WHERE A.courseID = C.courseID AND A.StudentID = C.StudentID 
     ORDER BY SnoozeFrom DESC ) AS latestSnooze , 
 (SELECT top 1 SnoozeTimes FROM [tblConsecutiveSnooze] D 
     WHERE A.courseID = D.courseID AND A.StudentID = D.StudentID 
     ORDER BY SnoozeFrom DESC ) AS snoozeTimes  
FROM [tblStudentAttendance] A INNER JOIN tblcourses 
     ON A.courseID = tblcourses.courseID

WHERE [lessonDate] > getdate()-21 
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblstudentCourses B WHERE A.courseID = B.courseID 
   AND B.[DateLeft] IS NULL AND A.StudentID  = B.StudentID)  

ORDER BY courseid , studentID, [lessonDate]
```

So what I am doing is trying to access all student attendance records (from tblStudentAttendance) within the last 21 days, when i have confirmed (via the EXISTS) that the student is indeed still registered to the course.

Those 2 sub SELECT queries can be combined into one, but that does not have an impact on the run time of the query.

What does seem to effect the run time greatly is the EXISTS condition. So any suggestions appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

```
Sql Plan: http://199.127.217.23/mm.sqlplan
```

**Indexes:**

- tblStudentAttendance (id, PK)
- tblCourses (courseID, PK)
- tblConsecutiveSnooze (id, PK)
- tblstudentCourses (id, PK)

Comment: Hi, can you post how many records you have in your tables, the cardinality of the columns, the indexes on your tables, the number of records you expect to be included by your WHERE clauses and the explain plan of the query please? It's unlikely anyone will be able to give you a comprehensive without this.

Comment: or at least, post the execution plan (if feasible, they can be rather big). Have you tried to analyse it?

Comment: Ok - just added the plan in the Post. i have looked, but dont really understand much. I'm not a sql techie ;)

Comment: I have no idea @kneidels ;-). I don't think it does, but anything is a start. Don't you have the table DDL as well so that we definitively know what indexes there are?

Comment: For starters please start using aliases in your queries that refer to the table in some way, instead of always using "A" and "B". For example, `tblstudentCourses` would naturally take `C` or `SC`.

Comment: Also, what version of SQL Server? Does `tblConsecutiveSnooze` have an index on the `CourseID` and `StudentID` columns?

Comment: @ErikE - Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64). And no, those are not indexes.  indexes posted above now.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the execution plan you posted you will find that adding the missing index could improve the query performance by up to 33%. You can try adding the following non-clustered index to the tblStudentCourses Table. You can change the index name to whatever suits you.

```
USE [hvps453_datab2]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NC_tblStuddentCourses_DL_SI_CI]
ON [dbo].[tblStudentCourses] ([DateLeft])
INCLUDE ([studentID],[courseId])
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a derived table with a row number to find the most recent SnoozeFrom record?  Alternatively a CTE could also be used.

```
SELECT A.courseid
, A.studentid
, attendanceStatus
, lessonDate
, ConsecSnooze.SnoozeFrom AS latestSnooze
, ConsecSnooze.SnoozeTimes AS snoozeTimes
FROM [tblStudentAttendance] A
    INNER JOIN tblcourses
    ON A.courseID = tblcourses.courseID
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT SnoozeFrom
                                , SnoozeTimes
                                , C.courseID
                                , C.StudentID
                                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.CourseID, C.StudentID ORDER BY SnoozeFrom DESC) AS RowNum
            FROM [tblConsecutiveSnooze] C
    ) as ConsecSnooze ON ConsecSnooze.courseID = A.courseID
        AND ConsecSnooze.StudentID = A.studentID
            AND ConsecSnooze.RowNum = 1
WHERE [lessonDate] > getdate() - 21
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tblstudentCourses B
    WHERE A.courseID = B.courseID
        AND B.[DateLeft] IS NULL
        AND A.StudentID = B.StudentID
    )
ORDER BY courseid
, studentID
, [lessonDate]
```

Comment: Thanks @Sprouts83, the query worked, but the time spent was the same ~75 secs.

Comment: Hmm I guess I don't see where they are different.  I see joins on StudentID and CourseID.  My apologies if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: @Ben The join conditions are identical, joining on `CourseID` and `StudentID`.

Answer (score 0):

If the primary way that you access `tblConsecutiveSnooze` is by `CourseID` and `StudentID`, then I *highly* recommend that you change the PK to be nonclustered and add a clustered index on `CourseID, StudentID`. This is far superior to just adding a nonclustered index and leaving the clustered PK on `id`. Furthermore, it's possible you don't even need the `id` column, if there are no FKs to it (that don't make sense to switch to `CourseID, StudentID`). While I am a proponent of surrogate keys, not every table needs them!

I'd also like to recommend that you stop naming columns simply `id`. A column name should be the same in every table it exists within, including its base table.